# Какие критерии получения знака "научный ассистент"?

Tags: поддержка, метки, правки, знаки, научный-ассистент

Добавил краткое описание для ряда меток, у которых его не было, но в прогресбаре оно не отразилось.

[image: 2/50]

Как было `2/50`, так и осталось. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Учитываются лишь правки полного описания метки, в том числе, создание новой метки с полным описанием, если верить [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/260198).

Comment: @Podushkoved с этим нужно на MSE идти. Но не думаю, что это сделают)